# Null User Id's recorded by firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

We are linking our firebase analytics data to BigQuery and upon analyzing found that the user id's are null for several users.

In what scenarios can this happen? and what is the solution for the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bad behavior was when the `user_id` property was populated with a value. The property `user_id` should be null except if you set it explicitly with a call to that function:

- android function: [`setUserId(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setUserId(java.lang.String))
- ios function: [`setUserId(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/interface_f_i_r_analytics.html#a9e70957b5c5f24a25e534e5def1ef432)

If you don't explicitly call `setUserId`, which is common, then the id you should use in BigQuery would be the `app_instance_id`.

My advice: call setUserId once you have a logged in user (in Facebook, Google sign-in or whatever method you offer). This will give you a cross-device ID. If the user is not logged in, don't call it, and use the `app_instance_id` id instead.

Note that the `app_instance_id` change if the user uninstall & reinstall your app.

Comment: Thanks did this behavior change after a version we have started seeing this only recently

Comment: AFAIK it was a server side fix so the behavior changed no matter which version of Firebase you are/were using.

Comment: I don't see `app_instance_id` in my BigQuery analytics table schema... Was it removed/renamed?

Comment: Is it now `user_pseudo_id`?

Comment: These are 2 different things. user_id Is added if the app call "setUserId" with a value. user_pseudo_id is always present. It's a way for you to identify with event come from the same user. Read more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid