# what suddenly lead to user id of all data set null by firebase

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, userid, firebase-analytics

I linked firebase data to bigquery. until 20160725, it worked fine. but from 20160726, I found the user_dim.user_id of data is set null. what happened to lead user_id set null?

Answer (score 3):

`user_dim.user_id` is only present if the developer called `setUserId()` and supplied their own user ID.

Early behavior of the exports might have not matched this guideline - but it does so now. For an auto-generated id, check `user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id`.

Comment: That is to say, developer must set user id by themselves ? user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id(which is  not unique) maybe changed after app updated or  removed .

Comment: Same question as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633755/null-user-ids-recorded-by-firebase/38716034#38716034 
Tracking a user specific id is indeed in the hand of the app developer as it would require user to sign-in to have a true user id. app_instance_id does not change when the app is updated, it only change after a user uninstall and reinstall the app.